# dynamic_pointer_cast unexpected behaviour

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr, make-shared

I'm building a factory class where I need to return a `unique_ptr` to a `BaseClass`. The returned pointer is made of a `DerivedClass` object that is converted to a shared pointer using `make_shared` and then converted to the desired `BaseClass` pointer as:

```
#include "BaseClass.h"
#include "DerivedClass.h"

std::unique_ptr<BaseClass> WorkerClass::DoSomething()
{

      DerivedClass derived;

      // Convert object to shared pointer
      auto pre = std::make_shared<DerivedClass>(derived);

      // Convert ptr type to returned type
      auto ret = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<BaseClass>(ptr);

      // Return the pointer
      return std::move(ret);
}
```

I'm getting this compiler error on `std::move`

```
error C2664: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr(std::nullptr_t) throw()' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty>' to 'std::nullptr_t'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=rfidaccess::BaseClass
1>          ]
1>          nullptr can only be converted to pointer or handle types
1>c:\project\dev\traansite1r\traansite1rcommon\tag.cpp(261): error C2664: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr(std::nullptr_t) throw()' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::shared_ptr<_Ty>' to 'std::nullptr_t'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=rfidaccess::BaseClass
1>          ]
1>          nullptr can only be converted to pointer or handle types
1>c:\project\dev\traansite1r\traansite1rcommon\tag.cpp(337): error C2664: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr(std::nullptr_t) throw()' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'rfidaccess::AARLocomotiveBaseClass' to 'std::nullptr_t'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=rfidaccess::BaseClass
1>          ]
1>          nullptr can only be converted to pointer or handle types
1>c:\project\dev\traansite1r\traansite1rcommon\tag.cpp(393): error C2664: 'std::unique_ptr<_Ty>::unique_ptr(std::nullptr_t) throw()' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'rfidaccess::AAREndOfTrainBaseClass' to 'std::nullptr_t'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ty=rfidaccess::BaseClass
1>          ]
1>          nullptr can only be converted to pointer or handle types
```

I'm using VS2012.

Why is it using something different than declared (`std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>`) ?

Is `dynamic_pointer_cast` not returning a `std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>` to ret ?

Comment: Do note that doing `return std::move();` for an automatic-storage-duration object local to the function is perfectly superfluous. It's implicit, and called [(Named) Returned Value Optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::shared_ptr` is not convertible to `unique_ptr`.

In your case, you just want the following:

```
std::unique_ptr<BaseClass> WorkerClass::DoSomething()
      return std::make_unique<DerivedClass>(/*args*/);
}
```